# How to render the pdf file in web view using android application?

Tags: android, web-services, pdf

I am working on web services related mobile application. when we call the below service url in a default browser, pdf file will be downloaded.

**Service Url**: http:/demo.com/microeforms/Pages/MicroeForms/Student/StudentProgressReports/StudentReport.aspx?Source=mobileapp&StudentCode=12/0429&AcademicYearId=751&AcademicYearText=2014
- 2015&StudentLevelId=151&StudentLevelText=Y1&StudentGroupId=562&StudentGroupText=1A&BranchId=100&BranchName=PS02-TEPS&Term=1

**Output**: Student Progress Report.pdf

But i have to call this service URL in a mobile browser kindly tell me how call this service url in a mobile application and how to display the downloaded pdf file in web view?

Comment: Hi All,bug is fixed thank you very much for sharing information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Like This.

```html
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://naseformsdemo.agilitylogistics.com/microeforms/Pages/MicroeForms/Student/StudentProgressReports/StudentReport.aspx?Source=mobileapp&StudentCode=12/0429&AcademicYearId=751&AcademicYearText=2014 - "));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: I am using file downloader concept,its working fine thank you Giridharan.